# Insert/Select data in foxpro database using c# .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I want to use FoxPro database in backend and c# .net in front end but i don't know how to connect with foxpro database in .net

For connectivity what code i use, please suggest...

Comment: google ado.net or check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee382825.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049891/how-do-i-read-a-foxpro-8-0-database-from-c

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/ankurmee/import-data-from-foxpro-dbf-database-to-datagridview-in-C-Sharp/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at .Net Interop.

Also take a look at West-Wind web connect. They have a framework that allows you to use the Visual studio IDE to create webforms but also use your VFP business logic and data source. This works well.

West wind also has a wwDotNetBridge that allows you to access .Net components from VFP.

Check out their website below.

http://west-wind.com/WestwindClientTools.aspx
http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/VFPDOTNETiNTEROP/VFPDOTNETINTEROP.HTM

Comment: Dear Jerry, I have Visual Studio 2010 IDE in front end and FoxPro Database in backend. I have to connect with FoxPro database for selecting some data from. I am new with FoxPro, I don't know what code I use to connect with FoxPro Database. I have only knowledge to connect with SqlServer...Help Please...

Comment: Here is an link that describes how to connect to foxpro data from .net:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa977092(v=VS.71).aspx    Also, here are a couple connection strings examples: Free table directory: Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=C:\SomeDirectory\MyVFPDataFolder;Password="";Collating Sequence=MACHINE      Database Container: Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=C:\SomeDirectory\MyVFPDataFolder\MyVFPDataBase.DBC;Password="";Collating Sequence=MACHINE

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you necessarily need to go the way of "interop", but get a basic understanding of connecting and querying data.

First, get Microsoft's OleDB provider [located here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839)

[Here is a sample doing a connection and running a simple query to get data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686530/how-do-i-create-a-new-vfp-oledb-table-from-an-existing-one-using-net/1691923#1691923) but this one sends the results to another VFP table instead of bringing back to C# for process/usage.

[This example shows Inserting records and uses parameters to help prevent any attempts at SQL-injection attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198197/how-to-insert-into-dbf-file-foxpro/9202623#9202623)

[And another using SQL-Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675610/how-to-update-a-table-using-oledb-parameters/2675922#2675922)

Once you get the basics down, its not that difficult.  I've actually made a simple "wrapper" class to centralize ensuring a valid connection, execute a given query and closing connection when done.  Then, I've just added methods to it for each thing I wanted to do (or could be subclassed too).  Anyhow, when I need to do a certain action, I would just call that function and pass in whatever parameter(s) was(were) needed.